# JS regex OR only picks first expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse IDs, label text, and input types ***OR*** "textarea" from this string:

```
var test = "<li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle"><label for="test1_1447826909520">test 1:</label> <input type="text" id="test1_1447826909520"></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle"><label for="test2_1447826918566">test 2:</label> <textarea id="test2_1447826918566" style="vertical-align:top;"></textarea></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle"><label for="test3_1447826926580">test 3:</label> <input type="number" id="test3_1447826926580"></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle"><label for="test4_1447826935118">test 4:</label> <input type="url" id="test4_1447826935118"></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle"><label for="test5_1447826944391">test 5:</label> <input type="email" id="test5_1447826944391"></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle"><label for="test6_1447826954174">test 6:</label> <input type="tel" id="test6_1447826954174"></li>"
```

here is my regex:

```
var re = /r="(.+?)">(.+?):.+?(?:pe="(.+?)"|(textarea))/gi
```

and I'm executing like this:

```
while ((matches = re.exec(test)) !== null) {
     console.log(matches[1]+', '+matches[2]+', '+matches[3]);
}
```

here is the result:

```
test1_1447826909520, test 1, text
test2_1447826918566, test 2, undefined // <---------
test3_1447826926580, test 3, number
test4_1447826935118, test 4, url
test5_1447826944391, test 5, email
test6_1447826954174, test 6, tel
```

the first and second cols are good, but the third is the result of the OR statement in my regex - `(?:pe="(.+?)"|(textarea))`

it will only capture the first expression.

The result in the second row is undefined because it is a "textarea".  If I switch the expressions in the OR the "textarea" shows and the rest are undefined.

where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *two* capturing groups here:

```
 (?:pe="(.+?)"|(textarea))
group 3-^      ^-group 4
```

Comment: yep - Thanks!  I thought the OR would make only a 3rd group.  Thanks again